# merge two table with different rows?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two tables that I would like to merge them based on 'Group' column but they have different rows. I have tried `merge ()` but I got `NA` for rows.

A:

```
Group   value

A        10
A         5
A         7
B         8
B         9
B         3
B         2
B         1
B         1
C         6
C         0
C         8
```

B:

```
Group   list   code

A        1     5
B        2     3
C        1     8
```

desire output:

```
Group   value   list   cod

A        10       1     5
A         5       1     5
A         7       1     5
B         8       2     3
B         9       2     3
B         3       2     3
B         2       2     3
B         1       2     3
B         1       2     3
C         6       1     8
C         0       1     8
C         8       1     8
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ues `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = "Group")
```

---

Or with `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 'Group', all.x = TRUE)
```